AWS CodePipeline says jar not found in target folder
This is my buildspec.yml file
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto21
  pre_build:
    commands:
    - echo In the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
    - echo Build started on `date`
    - mvn clean
    - mvn compile
    - mvn package
  post_build:
    commands:
    - echo Build completed on `date`
    - mv target/login-service-1.0.0.jar login-service-1.0.0.jar
artifacts:
  files:
  - "**/*"

on "- mv target/login-service-1.0.0.jar login-service-1.0.0.jar" this stage it says file not found. What could be the possible causes?
I tried altering buildspec file, but nothing worked so far

If you can run any commands in post_build, you could ls the files that are there.
